# How to integrate uPort mobile app with my app?

Tags: android, blockchain, ethereum

In uPort documentation [https://www.uport.me/#resources] there are steps to integrate uPort with a webapp, but can anybody share an example of how to integrate uport authentication for android based DApp ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of uport-connect in React Native:

https://github.com/uport-project/react-native-uport-connect

And a demo of it working with React Native apps:

https://github.com/uport-project/uport-react-native-demo

Currently there is active development for Android and iOS SDKs, as well as a port of the official UPort mobile app in native Android (Kotlin). However these are not finished yet. See:

https://github.com/uport-project/uport-android-sdk

https://github.com/uport-project/uport-android

The difference between apps that use uport-connect Vs. uport-android-sdk is that the former uses the official UPort app to keep track of identity, whereas apps built with the latter can keep track of identity and interact with the UPort contracts directly within the developer's app.

Comment: Hi. Can i send data like DID of login user to my cordova mobile app  ?